# py2exe `ImportError: No module named backend_tkagg`

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2exe

I am trying to make a windows executable from a python script that uses matplotlib and it seems that I am getting a common error.

> File "run.py", line 29, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "matplotlib\pyplot.pyc", line 95, in    File "matplotlib\backends__init__.pyc", line
>   25, in pylab_setup ImportError: No module named backend_tkagg

The problem is that I didn't found a solution while googling all over the internet.

Here is my `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
import matplotlib
import py2exe 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
setup(data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),console=['run.py'])
```

Comment: Take a look at [this mailing list post](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/714236-matplotlib-tkagg-windowsxp-importerror) and see if it could help you out a bit.

Comment: @Makoto didn't worked, Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. 
Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I used PyInstaller I think.

Answer (score 5):

First, the easy question, is that backend installed?  On my Fedora system I had to install it separately from the base matplotlib.

At a Python console can you:

```
>>> import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg
```

If that works, then force py2exe to include it.  In your config:

```
opts = {
  'py2exe': { "includes" : ["matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg"] }
}
```

Comment: `import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg` works and I added the option but the problem remains

Answer (score 2):

If you are using py2exe it doesn't handle .egg formatted Python modules.  If you used easy_install to install the trouble module then you might only have the .egg version.  See the py2exe site for more info on how to fix it.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs

Answer (score 0):

This works well

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
import matplotlib

sys.setrecursionlimit(12000)
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {
        "py2exe" : {
            "bundle_files":3,
            "compressed":True,
            "includes" : ["matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg"]
        }
    },
    windows = [{"script": "script.py"}],

```
zipfile = None,
```

data_files=matplotlib    data_files = matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to install the backend_tkagg

For centos -- **sudo yum install python-matplotlib-tk**

This should work.